# Angular canActivate router guard not working

Tags: angular

For some reason my cost-categories-details guard isn't working as intended. The routing to the cost-category-details works just fine when I give a valid "id" number or click on an item in my cost-categories component. If I type in "localhost/44300/cost-ca/42" then I should be redirected back to my cost-categories.component.html page since that 'id' does not exist in my data. However, the guard doesn't seem to work and redirects me to the cost-categories-detail page without any data when I type an id that doesn't exist.

If the "id" is null in the data, then I want to display an alert and route back to the cost-categories-list page. Please help!

cost-categories-details.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CostCategoriesDetailsGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    let id = +next.url[1].path;
    if (isNaN(id) || id < 1) {
      alert('Invalid well Id');
      this.router.navigate(['/cost-categories']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

app-routing-module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {path: '', component: CostCompareComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard]},
  {path: 'cost-categories', component: CostCategoriesComponent},
  {path: 'cost-categories/:id', component: CostCategoriesDetailsComponent, canActivate: [CostCategoriesDetailsGuard]},
  {path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
if (isNaN(id) || id < 1) {
  alert('Invalid well Id');
  this.router.navigate(['/cost-categories']);
  return false;
}
```

Is only checking whether the id is a number and if that number is greater than 1. There is no code in this guard to check whether there is an existing Id with that number.

Depending on the other parts of your code, you may be better off redirecting the "not found" from the details page itself. So when the code in the detail page requests a product with an id that is not found, it would use the `this.router.navigate` to navigate back.

Or consider using a route resolver to get the data. Then you could re-route from the route resolver without first going to the detail page.